# stopword analyser in Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I just created a stopword analyser like this

```
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "english_stopwords": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords": "_english_"
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "filter_english_stopwords": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "english_stopwords",
        "porter_stem"
      ]
    }
  }
}}}
```

and then query in elastic search like this

```
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "an clubbing",
      "fields": [
        "event_name",
        "event_place",
        "event_description"
      ],
      "analyzer": [
        "filter_english_stopwords"
      ]
    }
  }
}}}
```

it removes the `"an"` keyword from search which is fine but
it shows me all data having word **club not clubbing** 
I have to find all data having word **clubbing** only

```
        "_source": {
            "event_id": "1669",
            "event_name": "Exclusive Ladies Night Party",
            "regular_id": "56750ee601fcfffc058b4567",
            "event_place": "Asom Club Dwarka, Dwarka, New Delhi, India",
```

See event_place value.
Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what is the requirement. Sorry. You used bold letter and didn't provide any sample documents or desired results.

Comment: i have added my result there.... its shows result event_place with word Club not clubbing

Comment: What's the mapping of `event_place` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"porter_stem"` filter is transforming your `clubbing` search word in `club` and this is why it's matching `Asom Club Dwarka, Dwarka, New Delhi, India`. Remove the `porter_stem` filter and you should be good to go.